# Ansible double loop using subelements

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible playbook and I have the following variable:

```
contracts:
  - name: 'https'
    subjects:
      - name: 'permit'
        filters:
          - filter: tcp_443
```

A contract has multiple subjects and a subject can have multiple filters. The playbook needs to loop over this variable.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
- name: Task - Contract Subjects Have Filters
  contract_subject_to_filter:
    state: "present"
    tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
    contract: "{{ item..0.name }}"
    subject: "{{ item.1.name }}"
    filter: "{{ item.2.filter }}"
  loop: "{{ contracts | subelements('subjects') | subelements('filters') }}"
  tags: contract
```

> {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ contracts |
> subelements('subjects') | subelements('filters') }}): the key filters
> should point to a dictionary, got '({'name': 'https', 'subjects':
> [{'name': 'permit', 'filters': [{'filter': 'tcp_443'}]}]}, {'name':
> 'permit', 'filters': [{'filter': 'tcp_443'}]})'"}

How can I do a double loop (contracts has subjects and subjects have filters) in an Ansible playbook? I cannot change the variable structure or use a different Ansible module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatten the list, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ _my_list|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        _my_list: |-
          {% for i in contracts %}
          {% for j in i.subjects %}
          {% for k in j.filters %}
          - {name: {{ i.name }}, subject: {{ j.name }}, filter: {{ k.filter }}}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  my_list:
  - filter: tcp_443
    name: https
    subject: permit
```

Then, the iteration is trivial

```yaml
    - name: Task - Contract Subjects Have Filters
      debug:
        msg: |-
          state: "present"
          tenant: "tenant"
          contract: "{{ item.name }}"
          subject: "{{ item.subject }}"
          filter: "{{ item.filter }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    state: "present"
    tenant: "tenant"
    contract: "https"
    subject: "permit"
    filter: "tcp_443"
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much.